# Servo motor control maximum angle modification

Tags: arduino, pwm, servo, gear

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to modify a JX Servo PDI-6208MG 8KG Servo 120 Degree 0.07 sec, which matches the required speed, size, and torque, but make it rotate over 270°. I'm using an Arduino Uno with a PWM library, and have to set 12 fixed positions exactly in the 270° rotation range.

One example describes using 2 kΩ, 1/8 W resistors and making the servo rotate almost 360°.

The answer to *[turning positional servo motor more than 180 degrees](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/75442/turning-positional-servo-motor-more-then-180-degrees)* describes using microseconds.

Also, I've found some gear modification methods, but I don't know if that is possible with this motor.

And [359 Degree Servo Modification](https://www.instructables.com/359-Degree-Servo-Modification/).

The rotation with box manually is 190°, and without the box is 220° because of the pin on the gear contacts with limits on the box. Limitation on 220° from inside, looks like a potentiometer:

[image]

Comment: If you turn the output manually (with servo not powered) can you get 270 degrees? If not, take it apart and look for mechanical stops. Can these be removed?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott Hello, thank you for your feedback. Manually it rotates 190°. So, I have to find mechanical limits.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott I've edited with details and seems like it is impossible